# Implementing ActiveMQ Artemis monitoring using SolarWinds

Tags: activemq-artemis

Implementing monitoring for Artemis ActiveMQ using SolarWinds involves configuring JMX in the `bootstrap.xml` file. However, after making changes to the code, Artemis fails to start, and errors occur. Let's correct the grammar:

"After changing the code, Artemis does not start and throws errors."

`bootstrap.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema">

    <jaas-security domain="activemq"/>

    <server configuration="file:/D:/apache-artemis-2.31.2-bin/apache-artemis-2.31.2/bin/slave/etc//broker.xml"/>

    <!-- JMX Connector Configuration -->
    <connectors>
        <connector connector-name="jmx" socket-binding="jmx" security-realm="ManagementRealm"/>
    </connectors>

    <!-- Socket Binding Configuration for JMX -->
    <socket-binding name="jmx" port="1099"/>

    <!-- The web server is only bound to localhost by default -->
    <web path="web" rootRedirectLocation="console">
        <binding uri="http://0.0.0.0:8161">
            <app name="branding" url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
            <app name="plugin" url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
            <app name="console" url="console" war="console.war"/>
        </binding>
    </web>
```

Error:

```
D:\apache-artemis-2.31.2-bin\apache-artemis-2.31.2\bin\slave\bin>artemis.cmd run
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 21; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://activemq.apache.org/schema":connectors}'. One of '{"http://activemq.apache.org/schema":configurationFile, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema":configurationURI}' is expected.]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:453)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:387)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:356)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.dto.XmlUtil.decode(XmlUtil.java:114)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.factory.xml.XmlBrokerFactoryHandler.createBroker(XmlBrokerFactoryHandler.java:35)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.factory.BrokerFactory.createBrokerConfiguration(BrokerFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.factory.BrokerFactory.createBrokerConfiguration(BrokerFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Configurable.getBrokerDTO(Configurable.java:100)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Run.execute(Run.java:83)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.internalExecute(Artemis.java:219)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:165)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:157)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.main(Artemis.java:64)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 21; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://activemq.apache.org/schema":connectors}'. One of '{"http://activemq.apache.org/schema":configurationFile, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema":configurationURI}' is expected.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:512)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3596)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1972)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:830)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:571)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:71)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:45)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:216)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:150)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:385)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: If SolarWinds can scrape a Prometheus endpoint it may make more sense to configure the [Artemis Prometheus Metrics Plugin](https://github.com/rh-messaging/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin) rather than using JMX.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you got the idea that those elements could be configured in `bootstrap.xml`, but that is not correct. That looks like configuration from WildFly. In any event, remote JMX connectivity is configured in `management.xml`, e.g.:

```xml
<connector connector-port="1099"/>
```

This is commented-out by default.

Please refer to [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#remote-jmx-access) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To enable remote JMX access to Apache ActiveMQ Artemis and connect to it using JConsole

```
Configure management.xml
<connector connector-port="1099"/>

Configure artemis.profile
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
```

broker.xml

```
<!-- use a specific JMX domain for ActiveMQ Artemis MBeans -->
<jmx-domain>my.org.apache.activemq</jmx-domain>
```

Start Apache ActiveMQ Artemis:
Start or restart the Apache ActiveMQ Artemis server to apply the changes.

Connect with JConsole:
Now, you can connect to the Apache ActiveMQ Artemis server using JConsole.

Open JConsole. You can usually find it in the JDK's bin directory.
Choose the "Remote Process" option.
Enter the following service URL:

```
 service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
Adjust the hostname and port if you configured them differently.
Click "Connect".

In the solarwinds we are proviting the JMX "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi" and username and password in the agentless and achieve the monitoring for artemis active mq 

correct me if i am wrong
```

Comment: The `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost` system property is not strictly required. Also, `<jmx-domain>` is also not strictly required. You'd typically only set that if there were multiple brokers running in the same JVM (which is extremely rare).

Comment: Also, this configuration will only work if SolarWinds and ActiveMQ Artemis are running on the same machine (i.e. together on `localhost`).

Comment: solarwinds are different machine then what need to do ?
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://pro-qve-01:1099/jmxrmi sha;; i given like this in the solarwinds?